# Getting error in posting XML to webservice url in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to post XML Data using CURL in php. But getting the following error:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.

If anyone found any answer for this, please give the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML/PHP : Content is not allowed in prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999079/xml-php-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog)

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused when there is content before the XML code, making it invalid. More information can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/sax-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog/)

What it says, for completion:

**Solution**

This error message is always caused by the invalid XML content in the beginning element. For example, extra small dot “.” in the beginning of XML element.

Any characters before the `<?xml….` will cause above `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog` error message.

A small dot `.` before the `<?xml….`

```
.<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff>
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff>
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

To fix it, just delete all those weird characters before the “